# What it the fastest way to check if a string consists of three or more dashes in php?

Tags: php, regex, string

Is regex the only way? Is it slow?

Something like this?

```
preg_match("/^(\-){3,}/", $string);
```

Comment: If you want only dashes in your string you must add anchors `^` `$`

Comment: like i edited in now?

Comment: i dont know if its faster.. but you could explode the string using '-' as a delimiter and count the size of the array?

Comment: Do you want ONLY 3 or more dashes? No other characters? That's how I'm reading you question, but others aren't. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Only dashes

If you want the string to be *only* dashes, and there must be 3 or more:

```
$match = (preg_match('/^-{3,}$/', $string) === 1);
```

Another way without regex that seems to be about 25% slower (`isset` beats `strlen`):

```
$match = (count_chars($string, 3) === '-' && isset($string[2]));
```

## Adjacent dashes

If you want 3 or more dashes in a row, but there may be other characters (e.g. `foo---bar`):

```
$match = (strpos($string, '---') !== false);
```

## Some dashes

If you want 3 or more dashes anywhere (e.g. `-foo-bar-`):

```
$match = (substr_count($string, '-') >= 3);
```

Comment: I want 3 dashes **or more** in a row could be 100

Comment: If there are 100 dashes in a row, then there are 3 dashes in a row.

Comment: this would match even if some other stuff (not dashes) is inside the string or?

Comment: @Wayne'sWorld, yes. The count will return the exact amount of dashes, per http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php. So even if you had "this-is-a-substr_count-test-string" it will return integer 5

Comment: @Wayne'sWorld if you *only* want dashes, then yes, the regex is fastest.

Comment: I tested and yes it is, expected someone would introduce me to something I did not know about, thanks for the details.

Answer (score 0):

there is substr_count function.  might be good for counting characters

```
echo substr_count('fa-r-r', '-'); // outputs 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
function dashtest($str) {
   $rep = str_replace('-', '', $str);
   $length = strlen($str);
   return ( $length>2 && $rep =='' ) ? true : false;
}
```

an other way:

```
function dashtest($str) {
    for ($i=0 ; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
        if ($str[$i]!='-') return false;
    }
    if ($i<3) return false;
    return true;
}
```

the regex way:

```
if (preg_match('~^-{3,}+$~', $str)) { /*true*/} else { /*false*/}
```

Comment: The regex way is much better for long strings of dashes, like `str_repeat('-----------', 100)`.

Comment: I tested your functions, of course no real-life situation but looks like regex is faster. look my answer.

Comment: @Wayne'sWorld: I have quickly tested the three ways, and strangely (or not) the first way is the fastest with long strings. the second is 3x slower, and the third is near the first.

Comment: I tested it again with a long string, in my test regex is still fastest, anyway i am stupid to waste my time on this, i should go with regex without even coming to SO ;)

Comment: Do you make testes with "false" strings?

Answer (score -1):

I ran this test and funny thing is regex ist the fastest

```
<?php


function dashtest($str) {
   $rep = str_replace( '-', '', $str );
   $length = strlen( $str );
   return ( $length < 3 || $rep != '' ) ? false : true;
}

function dashtest2($str) {
    for ($i=0 ; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
        if ($str[$i]!='-') return false;
    }
    if ($i<3) return false;
    return true;
}



$string = '------------';



$start = microtime(true);

for ( $i=0; $i<100000; $i++ ) {
    dashtest( $string );
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
echo "\n";



$start = microtime(true);

for ( $i=0; $i<100000; $i++ ) {
    dashtest2( $string );
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
echo "\n";



$start = microtime(true);

for ( $i=0; $i<100000; $i++ ) {
    (preg_match('/^-{3,}$/', $string) === 1);
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
echo "\n";
```

output:

0.38635802268982

1.5208051204681 <- haha!

0.15313696861267

another try

```
$string = '----------------------------------------------------------------------------';
```

0.52067899703979

8.7124900817871

0.17864608764648

regex wins again

Comment: If you want to win a 0, add a `+` after the closing curly bracket. `^-{3,}+$`